# pl sql set variable in procedure

Tags: plsql

I am not sure how to set variables in a stored procedure which calls another stored procedure.  I want to save the value returned and use it later in another select.

I want to do something like this:

```
 PROCEDURE procName(bcur OUT IssCur)
 IS
cur2 IssCur;
extCur IssCur;
exlineno varchar2(30);

BEGIN
exlineno :=getExternlineno(exlineno,'50036648','00060');
open cur2 for SELECT concat(SUBSTR(susr2, 0, INSTR(susr2, '-')-1),'' ) from OrderDetail;
```

the stored procedure to call

```
 PROCEDURE getExternlineno(
oRetValue OUT varchar2,
pKey IN varchar2,
poNum IN varchar2)
AS
Begin
  select externlineno into oRetValue  from podetail where pokey = pKey and polinenumber    = poNum;
end getExternlineno;
```

once I figure out how to do that then I can also break up something like this(which doesn't understand the proc name:

```
      SELECT concat(concat(SUBSTR(susr2, 0, INSTR(susr2, '-')-1),'' ),' - ' || getExternlineno(exlineno,'50036648','00060')) from OrderDetail;
```

Comment: You should declare `getExternlineno` as function, not procedure.

Comment: Either you use the value by reference (`oRetValue OUT varchar2`), then you don't need `exlineno :=`in the calling procedure or you do it like Egor said. In your case a function looks better ...

Comment: Go for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Egor is right in his comment. You should declare `getExternlineno` as a function in order to use it inside an SQL query.

The function `getExternlineno` would then become:

```
FUNCTION getExternlineno(
pKey IN varchar2,
poNum IN varchar2)
RETURN VARCHAR
AS
DECLARE
oRetValue VARCHAR2(2000); -- Change the precision as per program's requirements.
Begin
  select externlineno into oRetValue from podetail where pokey = pKey and polinenumber = poNum;
end getExternlineno;
    /
```

Your `procName` procedure would then become:

```
PROCEDURE procName(bcur OUT IssCur)
IS
cur2 IssCur;
extCur IssCur;
exlineno varchar2(30);

BEGIN
exlineno := getExternlineno('50036648','00060'); -- Notice the change in number of arguments here.
open cur2 for SELECT concat(SUBSTR(susr2, 0, INSTR(susr2, '-')-1),'' ) from OrderDetail;
END procName;
/
```

And your SQL query would become:

```
      SELECT concat(concat(SUBSTR(susr2, 0, INSTR(susr2, '-')-1),'' ),' - '
             || getExternlineno('50036648','00060'))
        FROM OrderDetail;
```